# aws cf stack - How invoke ssm automation document?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

The simple question: how to invoke ssm automation document one time after Cf-stack was created? The automation document is located at the stack which is created. EB rule proposes a schedule, not bad. but I need it one time.

Comment: You can use a CustomResource that triggers on create only. Look at the CustomResource provider. It’s a light but helpful abstraction over raw CR.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.